# Python tkinter place put frame to the bottom

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code

```
class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.attributes('-zoomed', True)

        f1 = Frame(self.root, bd=1, bg="green", relief=SUNKEN)
        f2 = Frame(self.root, bd=1, bg="red", relief=SUNKEN)
        f3 = Frame(self.root, bd=1, bg="blue", relief=SUNKEN)

        split = 0.5
        f1.place(relx=0, relheight=1, relwidth=split)
        f2.place(relx=split, relheight=1, relwidth=1.0 - split)
        f3.place(height=50, width=self.screen_width)

app = App()
app.root.mainloop()
```

and the output is this
[image]

How to put the blue frame to the bottom of the window/screen?

Comment: Do you need a solution using `place`, or will you accept an answer with `pack` or `grid`? `The other two are superior for most tasks, including the one you're trying to create.

Comment: @BryanOakley I would accept pack if it will be give me fix width and height. I have tried grid but the frame/widget is not fix. If you change the green frame with an picture the red and blue will also adjust its width and height. I do not want them to adjust. If you can give me a solution in grid that will not adjust the layout then that would nice. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you specifically asked about `place`, but honestly, you should not use `place` except in very rare circumstances. The layout you're trying to achieve is very easy with both `grid` and `pack`.

Using `pack`:

```
f3.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
f1.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
f2.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Using `grid`:

```
# row zero takes up all extra vertical space
# column 0 and column 1 take an equal amount of all horizontal space
self.root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

f1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
f2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
f3.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")
```

Comment: I tied to change the f1 to an image but the width adjust http://pasteboard.co/F2TVG6U.png im using your grid code. How to maintain the equal width?