# How can I stop a function from another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, audio

I have a program, and I want it to play loading music, but stop after it's done.

I was thinking about this in another thread (multi-threading):

```
while True: 
    if Variables.StopMusic: 
        return
    else:
        playsound("blah.mp3", block=True)
```

But this would only run every time the music ends, so it wouldn't work right.

Here's my current code.

```py
def commence():
    global photo #This is necessary because https://stackoverflow.com/a/16424553/9654083
    #AKA, It prevents the image from getting garbage collected
    mbox.showinfo("Commencing download...","Press OK to start...")
    url = Widgets.video.get()
    if url == "":
        mbox.showerror("Error", "Next time please type a URL.")
    load = Toplevel(window)
    load.geometry("1000x1000")
    photo = getPhoto(load)
    if Variables.audioSelect.get():
        playsound("/usr/share/youtube-dl-gui/loading_music.mp3", block=False)
    termf = Frame(load, height=50, width=200)
    termf.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=YES) #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017472/python-tkinter-place-put-frame-to-the-bottom
    wid = termf.winfo_id()
    try:
        Popen(['xterm -into %d -geometry 200x50 -sb -e /bin/sh -c "youtube-dl %s;sleep 1;exit"' % (wid, url)], stdout=sstdout, stderr=sstdout, shell=True)
    except Exception as ename:
        mbox.showerror("ERROR!", "An error occured.")
        print(ename)

class Variables:
    audioSelect = IntVar()
    audioSelect.set(1)

class Widgets:
    video = Entry(window)
    text = Label(text="Please insert a URL.")
    audio = Checkbutton(variable=Variables.audioSelect, onvalue=True, offvalue=False, text="Add loading music?") #https://stackoverflow.com/a/16285194/9654083

Widgets.text.pack()
Widgets.video.pack()
Widgets.audio.pack()
Button(window, text="OK", command=commence).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Is there anything like killing a function in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using another music library for Python  that allows pausing/stopping.

In case it's useful to you, it's https://github.com/4br3mm0rd/mpyg321.